# Simple SQL query that works for Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I am looking for a small and simple query that works on Oracle and SQL Server.

It is used as a test query to check the connection.

For SQL Server we used `SELECT 1`, but in Oracle it would have to be `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`.

What we plan to use now is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (sometable)` but any ideas for an even simpler query are appreciated.

Comment: Two questions: where are you running this query from, and is the schema the same in Oracle and SQL Server?

Comment: An application server is running the query. I can not guarantee that the schema is (or will allways be) exactly the same but i have some tables with the same schema on both. I do not care for the result of the query, it just may not give an error.

Comment: Given the clarification on Oracle's behaviour my answer clearly doesn't work for you but I'll leave it up as it will work for other RDBMSs. Is there no way you can check your connection in the code that will send this query? At the least check which RDBMS it's trying to connect to and change the query it sends accordingly?

Comment: The application server doesnt offer this feature. I would have to change the test query every time i change the source from MSSQL (later use) to Oracle (test environment). I know that they should be equal, but this is not possible in my case. As i said, we have a test query - the question is just if there is an even more simple one.

Answer (score 2):

One simple option is to add a view to SQL Server called `DUAL` that just returns `1`, that way you can have a simple query that works the same in both environments:

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

If returning data from relations isn't important then:

```
SELECT 'Hello world';
```

will rely on a connection as much as anything else. Your RDBMS should return 'Hello world'. Tested on SQL server and PostgreSQL (don't have access to Oracle).

Comment: Oracle doesn't support a SELECT without a FROM. It would have to be FROM DUAL for Oracle

Comment: Thanks Jaloopa, I've added a comment to the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you write query in ANSI standard. It can be executed in all the RDMS.

May be you can try this query....

```
select ColumnName from TableName where 1=2
```

BTW, the DBProvider shld have come property to state of DB connectivity... which DB provider does ur application uses?

Comment: Whilst this does require both schemas to share at least one table name, I think this is what @AsconX implied they were already doing.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a query? You could create a simple stored procedure with the same name in both databases, that just returns a constant, and execute it from the application server.